# how to created autogenerated doc id using batch in firebase 9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to add multiple docs using **Firebase 9 modular** with an auto-generated id? I have the logic from the prev version, but I cannot make it work with 9. Please note that I need to add a none existing doc at this point does batch support, add or just set?

```js
array.forEach((doc) => {
var docRef = db.collection("col").doc(); //automatically generate unique id
batch.set(docRef, doc);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It is stated in this guide for [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes), If you do not need to read any documents in your operation set, you can execute multiple write operations as a single batch that contains any combination of set(), update(), or delete() operations.

For adding a batch in Firebase with autogenerated ID, you can follow this code:

```
import { writeBatch, collection, doc } from "firebase/firestore";

// Get a new write batch
const batch = writeBatch(db);

// Add a new document with a generated id
let ref = doc(collection(db, "user"))
batch.set(ref, {name: "Test user"});

// Commit the batch
await batch.commit();

console.log("Document written with generated ID: ", ref.id);
```